# What are the type of "commands" in "container_commands" in aws elastic beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

This is from aws docs.

[image]

I am wondering what is the type of commands? Is it bash? PowerShell or what is it?

Answer (score 1):

First off the definitions:

> **Commands** -
>   Execute commands *on the EC2 instance*. The commands run before the application and web server are set up and the application version file is extracted.
>
> **Container Commands**
>   Execute commands that affect your application source code. Container commands run after the application and web server have been set up and the application version archive has been extracted, but before the application version is deployed.

As you can see, these commands run on the EC2 instance that you configured Elastic Beanstalk to run.
So you should use Bash command for [Linux](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html#linux-container-commands) instances and Powershell commands for [Windows](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-windows-ec2.html#windows-container-commands) instances.

Comment: For Windows EC2 instance, it is just Windows cmd